# Teamcity 7 run custom dialog parameters values remembers from previous build

Tags: teamcity-7.1

Using teamcity i can add build parameters and force to ask a question every time i click on "Run" button (this call "Run custom build dialog").
But, for example, if i create a "checkbox" and run the build and check this checkbox, than on next time this checkbox will be checked already, but i want to make this checkbox UNCHECKED by default every time when i run the build(to force the user confirm his choice). 
I was tried to find some information on internet, but unfortunately unlucky.
Is this possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "by design" feature in TeamCity. There are two feature requests in TeamCity's tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17056, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21453. Please vote for one that suits you best.